# Silverlight failing with Cross Domain Error

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, iis-7

I have an application that is built using ASP.NET, with an embedded Silverlight Object that communicates with a WCF back end. It is set up like so:

Server 1: Hosts ASP.NET Website on IIS7

Server 2: Hosts WCF Application on IIS7

My Machine will try to access Server 1 over the internet to log in to the website. Server 1 will the authenticate the user using the WCF Web Service over our internal network on Server 2. I can do this but when it loads the silverlight object it crashes, complaining about CrossDomain/ClientAccessPolicy failure. So to be sure I put those two files on every folder in the inetpub/wwwroot on both Server 1 and 2, just to be sure. But I am still getting the same error.

When I run the application from Server 1, it can connect to the site through its local network IP and it all works, it also works when I run the ASP.NET application from Visual Studio 2010 on my own machine, with the web service references pointing to Server 2.

I am almost at my wits end, there have been so many red herrings that I have tried and none have worked. I am not even sure if it is Silverlight/WCF or the IIS configuration on each server that is breaking it.

If anyone can help me shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Stuart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to my problem. I was not realising that the Silverlight application was trying to access a web service that was restricted by firewalls, so I had to create another web service that would re-route through the website and to the original web service.

What a bloomin' pain!

Answer (score 2):

one idea could be to use fiddler and find the request which is making crossdomainpolicy xml request. Is that failing? Check the address it is pointing to. I debugged my issue using that. It was pointing to root of the server and my crossdomainpolicy xml was in WCF project folder.

Comment: I am using fiddler on my own machine to see what data is being sent, but as far as I can tell it is not even asking for the clientaccesspolicy, should I run fiddler on the server that is hosting the silverlight application?

Comment: I think you should see at least one request for crossdomainpolicy xml or clientaccesspolicy xml. Try clearing current requests in fiddler and running it afresh.

Comment: This is where I am getting confused, if I run fiddler on my own machine how will it know what requests are being made between Server 1 and Server 2? Although when I try to run fiddler on Server 1 it shows almost no traffic at all, unless I am misunderstanding how to use fiddler?

Comment: these requests are made by browser which is running your silverlight application. Does your page refresh (not the silverlight view but the browser page), if NOT then all requests are made between client-browser and the server 2 (which is hosting WCF project).